# Menu and submenus not showing on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html

I am working on a menu that looks like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Expenses</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="view.php">View My Expenses</a></li>    
            <li><a href="employeeExpense.php">View Expenses</a></li>    

            <li> <a href="#">View Deconts </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="viewAllDecont.php">Single Deconts</a></li>                                 
                    <li><a href="viewDecontsForAll.php">View All Deconts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li> <a href="#">Add Expenses </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="soccer.php">Soccer/Tennis Expenses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gym.php">Gym Expenses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="coffeeTea.php">Coffee/Tea Expense</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

It works perfectly on chrome and firefox, it does not work on IE.

The navigation CSS looks something like this:

```
nav {   
text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;  
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    }

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    z-index: 9999;

}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 10px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Am I using deprecated functions ? I know the -moz- tag works for Mozilla Firefox and the -webkit- works for Chrome, but it initially worked. I must have updated IE or something. I am using IE 9.

Comment: What doesn't work? The gradient? IE9 doesn't understand CSS gradients.

Comment: No need to use `-moz-linear-gradient` anymore, by the way: Firefox unprefixed it.

Comment: The menu shows like a list in Word:
*Home 
*Expenses 
  -My Expenses 
  -My Deconts 
  -Add Decont

Comment: The gradient doesn't work either. Any ideas on how I can work around that in IE9 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I noticed.

1.) Your code looks fine except for the lack of an ending  tag. This could have been a copy paste issue.

2.) IE8 and prior do not work with the nav tag. So have you verified that you are running in IE9 mode? Open developer tools to make sure (F12) in IE. Make sure both document and browser mode are not in compability mode and set to IE9 or whatever your current version is at the moment.

Comment: Hi Anthony Mason,
1) the </nav> tag would not paste in stackoverflow as much as I tried. 2) I am running IE9. How do I make it work in IE9 standard ?

Comment: Ah right, I managed to change it to IE9 standard. It just didn't refresh the 1st time I clicked it. I see the good one now. Thanks

Comment: I saw that in your initial post you were using IE9, I was merely asking if you were running in standard settings. By default on intranet IE, annoyingly, defaults to compatability mode which breaks modern code. Check Tools -> Compatability View Settings. Or F12 to open developer tools, and go to document settings to ensure the above mentioned configuration is set.\

Comment: And I didn't refresh the page to see your response :) I'm glad I could help

Comment: Did that, works good. I just didn't see it first time. Good point Anthony. I still don't understand why they would choose to show something by default like in an older version of that browser. It doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @Cataneo: IE9 doesn’t support `linear-gradient`. You *can* use a filter, but that can cause problems; try a background image, or even just a reasonable background colour. An inset `box-shadow` can help too.

Comment: IE by default will use compatability mode by default for intranet sites. So if that is the case then there is the explanation. You can change this via group policy or by opening IE and going into Tools -> Compatibility Settings -> If your site is listed remove it, also make sure that "Display Intranet Sites In Compatibility mode" is NOT checked. Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx

To see not only what I explained for the process but also their amazing reasoning.

Comment: Try using this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ . It is an amazing tool for gradient generation with CSS and supports *all* browsers. For instance: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9. Additionally, the reason the default is compatibility mode is the simple fact that most businesses do not like upgrading their systems or internal sites unless absolutely necessary. This leads to internal web applications to suddenly stop working correctly with Windows updates. This should be managed via GP.